# Inconsistent session issues between browsers and logging into my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have struggled for quite some time to make my app pretty "universal" in a sense. All I want to be able to do is login to my app just like every other app, and be able to use any browser, open multiple tabs (without having to re-login, etc.). However, I cannot seem to get this to work consistently and not quite sure what I need to do. I have a production URL (app.mydomain.io) and for development, I have a DNS entry in my localhost file that allows me to access app-dev.mydomain.io).

In my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file, it looks like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: "session_key_#{Rails.env}"
```

With that being said, here are the random/inconsistent issues I'm having with different web browsers:

**Brave Browser (private mode)**

When logging into my application, I can see that the the cookie is being assigned, but then its value switches a *second* time, followed by a "You must login first" as if my browser tried to get to an authenticated page, but the session was invalidated somehow.

I can only successfully login to my application upon authenticating a *second* time. When I open multiple tabs, everything works fine. It doesn't require me to re-login or anything. Perfect.

So the only issue I'm having with the Brave Browser is that I have to submit authentication twice for the session to actually be validated.

**Safari (private mode)**

With Safari, I can always authenticate to my application just one time. However, I cannot open multiple tabs of my application because it requires me to login each time. It's like the session cookie isn't being recognized by the new tab or something.

I should also mention that I'm using Devise in my Rails application for authentication, and so part of me also wonders if this could be playing a part in the session issues I'm experiencing, more so than the way it's stored.

Any thoughts on how I can go about fixing these inconsistent session issues between the various browsers? I don't have this issue with any other app -- Facebook, Gmail, Linkedin, Twitter, etc. Nothing. Just my Rails app, so I know it's not the browser and just something I'm not coding right.

Comment: Many browsers will actually sandbox each tab when you're in private mode - if the browser is not sharing the same session identifier cookies between tabs then this behavior is to be expected.

Comment: But then how do I resolve this? This can't be a browser issue although I understand what you're saying. This behavior doesn't occur for any web app except for mine.